# Linux OEL 6x - Compatibility with ACL

Tags: linux, unix, oracle, access-control-list, rhel6

Will the ACL [ Access control lists like getfacl, setfacl ] utility work fine with OEL 6x?
It works great with Solaris 5.9 but not sure OEL 6x will support ACL utilities

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there are Linux versions of [getfacl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getfacl) and [setfacl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl), their syntax may vary slightly but functionally they're similar, take a look at those links.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Linux supports the standard ACL utilities. OEL is partially derived from Red Hat, so you check the [documentation covering RHEL 6](http://rhce.co/rhel6/Create_and_manage_Access_Control_Lists_%28ACLs%29).

Oracle also has a quick command analogue guide for those migrating from Solaris:
https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OTNTaskFinder/Security#Security-ACL